# Is it possible to keep the same prompt for PSSessions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

When I use `Enter-PSSession` with Powershell I get a new prompt like

`[HOSTNAME]:>`

This is nice, but I'm wondering if there's a way to have it not do that, and just default to the regular Powershell prompt.

The reason I ask is that I already have the hostname set in my normal prompt function, so my prompt ends up looking like

`[HOSTNAME] <PWD> [HOSTNAME]>`

which is sort of unnecessary.

Is there any way to override this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine your prompt for remote session like this :

```
$session = New-PSSession MyRemoteServer
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    function prompt { your_prompt_here }
}
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
```

[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13693090/381149) for a prompt function that override the pre-prompt [computername]: